# Use Stackexchange account instead of Google account

Tags: support, login

I used Google account to login to stackoverflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/424023/algot

To login to another sites on Stack... I try to use it but it is impossible. I register new account on the same email:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176754/algot

How it could be merged or what I had to do to login to other sites in your network?

Comment: The accounts are linked - check your profile. You can also add a new OpenID from your profile page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ChrisF said in a comment, your accounts are linked together, so it looks like your login is working fine. Each site (except for meta sites that aren't Meta Stack Overflow) will create a separate account that will be linked to your master Stack Exchange account.

You can view which sites you've created accounts on on the Accounts tab in your profile.